# Prove $a_n = \frac{(-1)^{n+3}}{n}$ converges.

Tags: calculus

Prove $a_n = \frac{(-1)^{n+3}}{n}$ converges.

Here's what I have done:

$$\lim_{n\to∞} \frac{(-1)^{n+3}}{n} = 0$$

Given $\epsilon>0$ $\exists N>0$ such that if $n>N$ then $|a_n-0|<\epsilon$

$$n>N \implies |a_n-0|<\epsilon$$
$$\implies |a_n|<\epsilon$$
$$\implies |\frac{(-1)^{n+3}}{n}|<\epsilon$$
$$\implies |\frac{1}{n}|<\epsilon \implies \frac{1}{n}<\epsilon \implies n>\frac{1}
{\epsilon}$$

Therefore if $N>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$, for any $n>N$

$$|\frac{(-1)^{n+3}}{n}|< \frac{1}{n} < \epsilon$$

Thus the sequence converges.

I am not 100% sure if what I did was correct, I was wondering if anyone can confirm if what I did was correct, and if not can you give me hints or point out where I might of went wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep the part

> Given $\epsilon>0$ $\exists N>0$ such that if $n>N$ then $|a_n-0|<\epsilon$
>   $$n>N \implies |a_n-0|<\epsilon$$
>   $$\implies |a_n|<\epsilon$$
>   $$\implies |\frac{(-1)^{n+3}}{n}|<\epsilon$$
>   $$\implies |\frac{1}{n}|<\epsilon \implies \frac{1}{n}<\epsilon \implies n>\frac{1}
> {\epsilon}$$

but change (almost) every $\implies$ to $\Leftarrow$:

We want: $\epsilon>0$ $\exists N>0$ such that 
$$n>N \implies |a_n-0|<\epsilon$$
$$\Leftarrow |\frac{1}{n}|<\epsilon \Leftarrow \frac{1}{n}<\epsilon \Leftarrow n>\frac{1}
{\epsilon}$$